# Webrtc MediaStream for video only displayed if getUserMedia was called

Tags: reactjs, video, webrtc

I have a web frontend that's able to obtain a `MediaStream` from a remote `RTCPeerConnection`.

Once I get this `stream`, I pass it to a `<video>` tag with `autoPlay` set.

(Note: the frontend is in React, so we pass the stream as an `srcObject` with a `ref`.)

Everything works fine in Firefox.

In Chrome, the video is only displayed if I do this at application startup:

- call `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ ... })` with either `audio` or `video` set to true
- take the MediaStream returned by `getUserMedia`, and keep it in a global or top-level variable

Now, that does not make any sense to me since:

- I don't want to ask users for permission to access their microphone or webcam in order to *display* a video
- This only happens in Chrome, and Firefox works fine
- This happens both on `localhost` and `https://` "public" domains, so it's probably not a security issue
- This does not seem to be affected by playing with the `autoPlay`, `controls`, etc... attributes of the `<video>` tag.

Anything obvious I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome introduced [autoplay restrictions in 2018](https://webrtchacks.com/autoplay-restrictions-and-webrtc/). These are not in effect when getUserMedia is active.
If your application logic works when Chrome is started with --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required this suggests this is the case. The article also has some background information and possible workarounds like introducing a user gesture.

(and no, these restrictions don't make sense...)

Comment: Unfortunately, even `--autoplay-policy=...` does not change anything. I'm really confused...

Comment: have you checked if the underlying connection gets established and receives frames? chrome://webrtc-internals will display that